# How to return a reference to a sub-value of a value that is under a mutex?

Tags: rust

I have a structure that looks somewhat like this:

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    data: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>>>>,
}
```

I can easily get a lock on the mutex and query the underlying `HashMap`:

```
let d = s.data.lock().unwrap();
let v = d.get(&1).unwrap();
println!("{:?}", v);
```

Now I want to make a method to encapsulate the querying, so I write something like this:

```
impl MyStruct {
    pub fn get_data_for(&self, i: &i32) -> &Vec<i32> {
        let d = self.data.lock().unwrap();
        d.get(i).unwrap()
    }
}
```

This fails to compile because I'm trying to return a reference to the data under a `Mutex`:

```
error: `d` does not live long enough
  --> <anon>:30:9
   |
30 |         d.get(i).unwrap()
   |         ^
   |
note: reference must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 28:53...
  --> <anon>:28:54
   |
28 |     pub fn get_data_for(&self, i: &i32) -> &Vec<i32> {
   |                                                      ^
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 0 at 29:42
  --> <anon>:29:43
   |
29 |         let d = self.data.lock().unwrap();
   |                                           ^
```

I can fix it by wrapping the `HashMap` values in an `Arc`, but it looks ugly (`Arc` in `Arc`) and complicates the code:

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    data: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<i32, Arc<Vec<i32>>>>>,
}
```

What is the best way to approach this? Is it possible to make a method that does what I want, without modifying the data structure?

[Full example code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=1b612a0968b0666f5fc414c395715d0a&version=stable&backtrace=0).

Comment: Nice question. I was expecting a `map()` method on `MutexGuard`, like [`Ref::map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Ref.html#method.map)... Why isn't there one? \*\_\*

Comment: ```
impl MyStruct {
fn with_data<F : Fn(&Vec<i32))> (f : F) { ... }
}
```
Would that work? Basically just let the user provide a function that will modify that data when under lock, instead of trying to return it?

Comment: @dpc.pw Yep. I thought about closure approach too... Not very beautiful, but does what I need... The best solution would be something like `map()` as Lukas mentioned, or some kind of weird lifetime manipulation magic, but I can't think of any...

Comment: Closure method is commonly used through rust code for references, borrows etc.

Comment: [It's kind of possible](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b2e483fa6b65d762f03b7137cbe686a0&version=stable&backtrace=0). This code is not very nice tho, because it will do the lookup every time `deref()` is called. I don't think you can do any better in safe Rust. But I'd love to be proven wrong here.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt I think you have the right idea but the wrong approach, I think you need a `struct{MutexGuard<'a>,&'a Inner}` with a `deref(_mut)` and `map` method. That should allow arbitrary remapping without waiting for a lock every time in safe Rust.

Comment: @Jsor I'd love to see that in action ;-)

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt [Evidently `MutexGuard::map` would be unsound](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/30834#issuecomment-180284290)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This solution is similar to @Neikos's, but using [owning_ref](https://crates.io/crates/owning_ref/) to do hold the `MutexGuard` and a reference to the `Vec`:

```
extern crate owning_ref;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::{Mutex,MutexGuard};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::vec::Vec;
use owning_ref::MutexGuardRef;

type HM = HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>>;

pub struct MyStruct {
    data: Arc<Mutex<HM>>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn new() -> MyStruct {
        let mut hm = HashMap::new();
        hm.insert(3, vec![2,3,5,7]);
        MyStruct{
            data: Arc::new(Mutex::new(hm)),
        }
    }
    pub fn get_data_for<'ret, 'me:'ret, 'c>(&'me self, i: &'c i32) -> MutexGuardRef<'ret, HM, Vec<i32>> {
        MutexGuardRef::new(self.data.lock().unwrap())
               .map(|mg| mg.get(i).unwrap())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s: MyStruct = MyStruct::new();

    let vref = s.get_data_for(&3);

    for x in vref.iter() {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

This has the advantage that it's easy (through the `map` method on `owning_ref`) to get a similar reference to anything else reachable from the `Mutex` (an individual item in a `Vec`, etc.) without having to re-implement the returned type.

Comment: The library has a type called `MutexGuardRef` why not use that? http://kimundi.github.io/owning-ref-rs/owning_ref/type.MutexGuardRef.html

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't noticed `MutexGuardRef`!

Comment: @ChrisEmerson Is it possible to modify `get_data_for` method so it would not `unwrap` the result of `get` function and would return `Option`? I tried to do it myself but cannot get around `conflicting lifetime requirements` errors

Answer (score 20):

The [`parking_lot`](https://docs.rs/parking_lot/) crate provides an implementation of Mutexes that's better on many accounts than the one in `std`. Among the goodies is `MutexGuard::map`, which implements an interface similar to `owning_ref`'s.

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use parking_lot::{Mutex, MutexGuard, MappedMutexGuard};
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct MyStruct {
    data: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>>>>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn get_data_for(&self, i: &i32) -> MappedMutexGuard<Vec<i32>> {
        MutexGuard::map(self.data.lock(), |d| d.get_mut(i).unwrap())
    }
}
```

[You can try it on the playground here.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d715ce55c8980899c232f0e54c013996)

Comment: This answer is so underrated. Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for, and I'd never think to look for it in `parking_lot`.

Answer (score 8):

This can be made possible by using a secondary struct that implements `Deref` and holds the MutexGuard.

Example:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, MutexGuard};
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::ops::Deref;

pub struct Inner<'a>(MutexGuard<'a, HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>>>, i32);

impl<'a> Deref for Inner<'a> {
    type Target = Vec<i32>;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        self.0.get(&self.1).unwrap()
    }
}
pub struct MyStruct {
    data: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>>>>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn get_data_for<'a>(&'a self, i: i32) -> Inner<'a> {
        let d = self.data.lock().unwrap();
        Inner(d, i)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut hm = HashMap::new();
    hm.insert(1, vec![1,2,3]);
    let s = MyStruct {
        data: Arc::new(Mutex::new(hm))
    };

    {
        let v = s.get_data_for(1);
        println!("{:?}", *v);
        let x : Vec<_> = v.iter().map(|x| x * 2).collect();
        println!("{:?}", x); // Just an example to see that it works
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I decided to mark Chris' answer as accepted, because `owning_ref` does not require to make an intermediate type. But more importantly, as Lukas pointed in similar suggestion in comments, this will invoke `map()` closure on each `deref()`. On other hand, `owning_ref` invokes lookup only once (at least in cases I have tested).

Answer (score 5):

Here's an implementation of the closure-passing approach mentioned in the comments:

```rust
impl MyStruct {
    pub fn with_data_for<T>(&self, i: &i32, f: impl FnOnce(&Vec<i32>) -> T) -> Option<T> {
        let map_guard = &self.data.lock().ok()?;
        let vec = &map_guard.get(i)?;
        Some(f(vec))
    }
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4a0f045c2ebd6c539f91ed5a62deb5c8)

Example usage:

```rust
s.with_data_for(&1, |v| {
    println!("{:?}", v);
});
```

```rust
let sum: i32 = s.with_data_for(&1, |v| v.iter().sum()).unwrap();
println!("{}", sum);
```

Answer (score 4):

As described in [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423), the [Rental crate](https://crates.io/crates/rental) allows for self-referential structs in certain cases. Here, we bundle the `Arc`, the `MutexGuard`, and the value all into a struct that `Deref`s to the value:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate rental;

use std::{
    collections::HashMap, sync::{Arc, Mutex},
};

use owning_mutex_guard_value::OwningMutexGuardValue;

pub struct MyStruct {
    data: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>>>>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn get_data_for(&self, i: &i32) -> OwningMutexGuardValue<HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>>, Vec<i32>> {
        OwningMutexGuardValue::new(
            self.data.clone(),
            |d| Box::new(d.lock().unwrap()),
            |g, _| g.get(i).unwrap(),
        )
    }
}

rental! {
    mod owning_mutex_guard_value {
        use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, MutexGuard};

        #[rental(deref_suffix)]
        pub struct OwningMutexGuardValue<T, U>
        where
            T: 'static,
            U: 'static,
        {
            lock: Arc<Mutex<T>>,
            guard: Box<MutexGuard<'lock, T>>,
            value: &'guard U,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = HashMap::new();
    data.insert(1, vec![1, 2, 3]);
    let s = MyStruct {
        data: Arc::new(Mutex::new(data)),
    };

    let locked_data = s.get_data_for(&1);
    let total: i32 = locked_data.iter().map(|x| x * 2).sum();
    println!("{}", total);

    assert!(s.data.try_lock().is_err());

    drop(locked_data);

    assert!(s.data.try_lock().is_ok());
}
```