# How can return a reference to an item in a static hashmap inside a mutex?

Tags: rust, lazy-static

I am trying to access a static hashmap for reading and writing but I am always getting error:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Mutex;

pub struct ModuleItem {
    pub absolute_path: String,
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref MODULE_MAP: Mutex<HashMap<i32, ModuleItem>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
}

pub fn insert(identity_hash: i32, module_item: ModuleItem) {
    MODULE_MAP
        .lock()
        .unwrap()
        .insert(identity_hash, module_item);
}

pub fn get(identity_hash: i32) -> Option<&'static ModuleItem> {
    MODULE_MAP.lock().unwrap().get(&identity_hash).clone()
}
```

But I am getting an error on the get function `cannot return value referencing temporary value`

I tried with `.cloned()`, `.clone()` or even nothing but I don't manage to get it to work. Can you help me?

Comment: Removed this [duplicate target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40095383/how-to-return-a-reference-to-a-sub-value-of-a-value-that-is-under-a-mutex) because the nature of this question has too many different subtleties which do not apply to the linked question, and the two sets of answers seem different enough to merit a distinction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried with .cloned(), .clone() or even nothing but I don't manage to get it to work. Can you help me?

All `Option::clone` does is clone the underlying structure, which in this case is an `&ModuleItem` so it just clones the reference, and you still have a reference, which you can't return because you only have access to the hashmap's contents while you hold the lock (otherwise it could not work).

`Option::cloned` actually clones the object being held by reference, but doesn't compile here because ModuleItem can't be cloned.

First you have to return a `Option<ModuleItem>`, you *can not* return a reference to the map contents since the lock is going to be released at the end of the function, and you can't keep a handle on hashmap contents across mutex boundaries as they could go away at any moment (e.g. an other thread could move them, or even clear the map entirely).

Then copy the ModuleItem, either by deriving `Clone` on `ModuleItem` (then calling `Option::cloned`) or by creating a new ModuleItem "by hand" e.g.

```py
pub fn get(identity_hash: i32) -> Option<ModuleItem> {
    MODULE_MAP.lock().unwrap().get(&identity_hash).map(|m| 
        ModuleItem { absolute_path: m.absolute_path.clone() }
    )
}
```

If you need to `get` keys out a lot and are worried about performances, you could always store `Arc<ModuleItem>`. That has something of a cost (as it's a pointer so your string is now behind *two* pointers) however cloning an Arc is very cheap.

To avoid the double pointer you could make `ModuleItem` into an unsized type and have it store an `str` but... that's pretty difficult to work with so I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

The function `get` cannot use a static lifetime because the data does not live for the entire life of the program ([from the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html)):

> As a reference lifetime 'static indicates that the data pointed to by the reference lives for the entire lifetime of the running program. It can still be coerced to a shorter lifetime.

So you have to return either a none-static reference or a copy of the value of the `HashMap`. Reference is not possible because [`MODULE_MAP.lock().unwrap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.lock) returns a `MutexGuard` which is a local and therefore a temporary variable that hold the `HashMap`. And `get()` of the `HashMap` returns a reference.

Due to the fact that the temporary `MutexGuard` will be destroy at the end of the function, the reference returned by `get` would point to a temporary value.

To fix this, you could make `ModuleItem` clonable and return a copy of the value:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Mutex;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct ModuleItem {
    pub absolute_path: String,
}

lazy_static::lazy_static! {
    static ref MODULE_MAP: Mutex<HashMap<i32, ModuleItem>> = Mutex::new(HashMap::new());
}

pub fn insert(identity_hash: i32, module_item: ModuleItem) {
    MODULE_MAP
        .lock()
        .unwrap()
        .insert(identity_hash, module_item);
}

pub fn get(identity_hash: i32) -> Option<ModuleItem> {
    MODULE_MAP.lock().unwrap().get(&identity_hash).cloned()
}
```

Comment: Thx for the 2 answers. Both seem to work. Was is actually the difference between them?

Comment: In the other answer you have to copy the data manually through the `map` function. In my answer the copying is done by deriving from `Clone` and using the `cloned` method