# How to get rid of "cannot return value referencing temporary value" error

Tags: rust, reference

I'm trying to implement a method that returns a `RwLockReadGuard` of a struct contained into a `HashMap` (itself in a `RwLock`).

The function below:

```rust
pub fn get_pair<'a>(&self, name: &str) -> Option<TradePairHandle> {
    if let Ok(ref pair) = self.pairs.read() {
        if let Some(p) = pair.get(name) {
            if let Ok(r) = p.read() {
                Some(TradePairHandle::new(r))
            } else {
                None
            }
        } else {
            None
        }
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

raise the following compilation error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/lib.rs:76:21
   |
73 |         if let Ok(ref pair) = self.pairs.read() {
   |                               ----------------- temporary value created here
...
76 |                     Some(TradePairHandle::new(r))
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value
```

referencing data owned by the current function

How to do this the correct way?

There is the full [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cce9eb42776896f8bce563a6f384c864)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32682876/is-there-any-way-to-return-a-reference-to-a-variable-created-in-a-function)

Comment: I m' afraid not, in my example the function don't return a reference

Comment: Your function does return a reference, since `TradePairHandle` contains a `RwLockReadGuard`, which in turn holds a reference. However, it's not entirely accurate that the value that reference is pointing to is "created" inside your function.

Comment: The problem is rather that the outer lock, the one you grab in the first line of the function, will be released when returning from the function, so any reference you obtain from inside that lock will become invalid at that point.

Comment: Does this question help? [How to return a reference to a sub-value of a value that is under a mutex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40095383)

Comment: The easiest way would be to keep an `Arc<RwLock>` in your `TradePairHandle`. If you want it to stay unlocked, you can create a struct that will keep the `RwLockReadGuard` together with the `Arc<RwLock>`, using the `rental` crate to handle the self-reference.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes, this question kind of helped, thank you! But now, using owning_ref I have another error. I updated the question.

Comment: @Aurel This is a completely separate question and should be asked as a new question.

Comment: @SvenMarnach ok, There it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63523566/how-to-handle-cannot-infer-an-appropriate-lifetime-for-autoref-due-to-conflicti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Sven Marnach, I tried a different approach with `owning_ref` crate. Now the method get_pair looks like this:

```rust
pub fn get_pair<'a, 'me: 'a>(
    &'me self,
    name: &str,
) -> RwLockReadGuardRef<'a, TradePairHashMap, Arc<RwLock<TradePair>>> {
    RwLockReadGuardRef::new(self.pairs.read().unwrap()).map(|pairs| pairs.get(name).unwrap())
}
```

And compile without errors. Thanks again!